# Not able to 'unset' environmental variable permanently - UBUNTU

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I set environment variable using `export CATALINA_HOME=/home/chirag/Softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.56` before some time from the terminal.

But now i want to unset this variable premenantly.

I use `unset CATALINA_HOME` to remove that variable but when I open other terminal that variable is available with the same value.

How can I remove the 'env variable' permanently ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you have to figure out where you set that variable in the first place.  Do you know where you set it before?  Simply setting it in the terminal is not enough to make a 'permanent' env variable

Comment: No I don't know where that variable is set at first time.

Comment: In my home directory I found `.bashrc` file and line `export CATALINA_HOME=/home/chirag/Softwares/apache-tomcat-7.0.56` at the end of the file. So I remove that line ?

Comment: Thanks, I remove line containing CATALINA_HOME variable and it works.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  I've moved my comments into an answer so you can accept it as the valid answer and mark the question as 'solved'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The environment variable is always going to be set if it's present in your configuration files for your system's environment variables or your own login profiles.

Open each of these files and search for a line that has `export CATALINA_HOME`, and remove the line (or comment it out) where present:

- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`

Once removing the line from the file, log out, and log back in (if in a terminal, just close the terminal and reopen it).  If it was in `/etc/environment` then consider rebooting the system first.

With the `export` line gone, the variable will be 'permanently unset' until the line is readded to one of those files.

Comment: In my case I had to comment out `export var` in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is in none of these, yet set when I launch a terminal...

Comment: @Xerus Sounds like there might be something else called from one of these (check all the included filepaths inside each of these too) which sets `JAVA_HOME`.  You might need your own question for this one, though.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement the existing good answer, here's a simple line to help you to find the file you need to edit, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6153342/6723250):

`egrep -lir "export variable" /etc/environment /etc/profile ~/.profile ~/.bashrc`

The word enclosed in quotes is the name of the environment variable it will search for.

It will provide you with the filename, then you just need to find the corresponding exprot line and comment or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

add `unset CATALINA_HOME` to the shell file (.bashrc or .zshrc)